# Provisioning a Device without Xcode

Tags: ios, file, profile, provisioning

[According to Apple](http://goo.gl/O7nhk), in order to create a provisioning profile file I need Xcode. Is there a way to generate this file without Xcode?

I have a valid developer certificate, but this is not enough to run applications on my device.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 4):

You can provision applications ye olde fashioned way at the iOS Provisioning Portal : http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action. You should be able to install the result with iTunes (this is how ad-hoc profiles are added).

Edit: All of this assumes you have a developer account.